# Webscraping data after clicking a link

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a website like https://florida.arrests.org/index.php?county=1 wherein I want to capture data which is getting displayed after clicking on a name.

I am trying to use beautiful soup but  success.Is there any other method to do it or any particular code snippet where we can click on the name link and capture that data.

Comment: There is no real link to click.  The link is created by JavaScript on the fly. Here it isn't too difficult to figure out the url.  For each profile you can parse the html to get the elements you need to construct the url.  For `<div class="profile-card">
                                    <div class="title"><a data-fancybox="" data-src="/Arrests/Carl_Rowe_39798548/?d=1">Carl<br>Rowe</a></div>` you would want to extract `/Arrests/Carl_Rowe_39798548`.  The url of the data you want is `"https://florida.arrests.org" + "/Arrests/Carl_Rowe_39798548"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to imitate a browser in order to push a button on a webpage. You can use the selenium library to do this:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/